# Convert all the data of table (which have both encoding data) into single encoding either utf8 or latin1

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

We have table which consists of two different encoding data (utf8 and latin1) which has been inserted from two different use cases of application. 
We are getting broken strings issue for other languages text if we get the data in one encoding.We need to convert total table data into single encoding.

Eg:
Table X
id  name        data encoded 
1   ébarber  - utf8
2   à gogo   - latin1

if we use "latin1" connection charset, we get issue with "ébarber"(broken strings).
if we use "utf8" connection charset, we get issue with "à gogo"(broken strings).

How can we convert this table data into single encoding either utf8 or latin1?
 Please share your thoughts to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  But it is painful.

1. Convert to `BINARY`
2. Identify which rows contain which encoding.  This can be automated, but may not be 100% correct.
3. Do a special `UPDATE` against those rows.
4. Convert to `utf8`.

Details:

Step 1:  Convert to binary:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...; -- with suitable matching other stuff, or
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col BLOB ...;  -- if it were TEXT.
```

Step 2:  Find latin1 lines (negate the following):

`SELECT HEX(col) ...` extracts hex for use with the regexp below

This regexp checks for utf8 (actually utf8mb4):

```
/^(
     [\xC2-\xDF] [\x80-\xBF]

   |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]
   | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
   |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]

   |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
   | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}
   |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}
)+/ox
```

Combining those should tell you if a row is *probably* utf8.

Step 3:  This converts a column (`col`) from latin1 encoding to utf8:

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(col USING latin1) USING utf8)
```

Step 4:  Get it to be utf8:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...; -- or
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col TEXT ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

**Caveat!**  While the individual parts of what I have told you are known to work, the cobbled-together combination has *not* been tested.  I strongly suspect there will be some form of hiccups.